# How to decode the video in client side

Tags: c++, opencv, streaming, video-streaming, client-server

I'm try to stream live video using OpenCV C++. In the Serverside  catch the web cam video then encode it and sent to the client. when I try to decode it in client side It can't do.

`std::vector<char> buf(recvbuf, recvbuf + recvbuflen);
// error here
cv::Mat matrixJprg = cv::imdecode(cv::Mat(buf), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
pYuvImage = cvCloneImage(&(IplImage)matrixJprg);`

[Picture can see some data are lost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sTrg.png)

server code encoded part.

```
    std::vector<int> p;
    p.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION);
    p.push_back(10);
    std::vector<unsigned char> buf;
    cv::imencode(".png", cv::cvarrToMat(image), buf, p);

    imageSize = buf.size();

    char* encodedBuffer = (char*)buf.data();

    char* sendBuffer = new char[buf.size()];

    memcpy(sendBuffer, encodedBuffer, buf.size());

    sendData = (char*)buf.data();

    hdr.dataLength = htonl(imageSize);
    hdr.encoded = htons(1);

    mSocket->writeData((char*)(&hdr), sizeof(hdr));
    mSocket->writeData(sendBuffer, imageSize);
```

I try to stream video only server side not to sent it to client, encode and decode video in server side it's work fine.
pls someone help me to fix this problem.

Comment: can you try `Mat rawData  =  Mat( 1, cols*rows, CV_8UC1, buf); cv::Mat matrixJprg = cv::imdecode(rawData , CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);` assuming that buf holds the streamed raw data memory. is your line std::vector<char> buf(recvbuf, recvbuf + recvbuflen); correct? did you verify that it's identical to the data you've sent?

Comment: ya, std::vector<char> buf(recvbuf, recvbuf + recvbuflen); is  correct, It can catch the passing data. but the problem is " cv::Mat matrixJprg = cv::imdecode(cv::Mat(buf), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR); "  doesn't identify  the passing data.